# Use of object.getClass() method in reflection api

Tags: java, api, reflection

How to retrieve an object name that reflects the package name by using the [object.getClass()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

[Finding out the object of the class](http://www.roseindia.net/java/reflect/Object.shtml)

This illustrates how to retrieve an object name that reflects the package name by using the object.getClass() method